# Notification is not working after android studio updation

Tags: android, notifications

I used the code given below. It was working perfectly before android studio updated. The old project which I created is also showing the notification. But in new projects it is not working. Can someone help?

```
notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setContentText("Stand Up and dance!!")
            .setContentTitle("Stand Up")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);



notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
```

Comment: After update android studio, What is android version? and gradle version?

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya Android Studio - 3.0.1 , Gradle version - 2.14.1 , Android plugin version - 2.2.1